# Store JSON data throughout Spring Boot Runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model, autowired

I have a spring boot application and uploading some configurations from a file into my spring boot as

```
{
  "importer": {
    "name": "Project XYZ",
    "description": "This project belongs to XYZ. It contains __ variants which are related.",
    "root": "./src/test/resources/Project/Project1"
  },
  //and some other configurations
 }
```

I also have my model class for this as

```
@Data
public class AssetRootConfig {

    @Id
    private String key;
    private AssetImport importer;
    //some configurations
}
```

Now I want to store/persist these values and use it throughout my spring boot runtime by instantiating / @Autowiring the model class just once and not @Autowiring AssetRootConfig in all classes to use it. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Create and Register a Bean for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are flexible on the JSON restriction you could put your structure in your properties file and use [@ConfigurationProperties](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) for deserialisation into your model. But then you `AssetRootConfig` would not be persisted in any database but rather represent a certain part of your configuration.

If that is not an option you can use [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html) for invocation of your code after startup. Then you can read your JSON from a file an persist it using some kind of repository (if it is not already persisted ;)). Once saved you could use the repository for accessing this particular entity.